# What's the best way to present a feature as free, but only if requested

Tags: usability, user-expectation, e-commerce, copywriting, microinteractions

There's this feature we have that some customers really want. And we're going to be including it for free. However, from an economics perspective, there are a ton of savings to not having users use this feature.

What's the best way to present a feature as included, but only if you request it. Here are some examples that I could come up with:

- XYZ included when requested.
- Free XYZ included upon request.

Are there other ways to make this sound better?

Comment: Can you share your efforts so far, with some mocks showing the context? It's important to see how users will encounter this, and what you've tried, or are considering.

Comment: There are two options I thought about: “XYZ optionally included for free” or “Free XYZ (optional)”. But it is hard to tell if you want the clearer wording of the first or the catchier wording of the latter. Without knowing more context I can not add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question because it involves weighing up the right balance between a business and user requirement decision.

You could almost argue that if some customers really want this and would be willing to pay for it, then you could implement different plans that might be costed based on usage or licence seats.

Without knowing too much more about the circumstances, it seems contradictory to cite economic/financial reasons not to charge for something that some customers really want if they are willing to pay for it. You still incur the cost for having to provide it to the customer, so why not try and validate the assumption of whether they are willing to pay for it?

Thinking further down the track, it is even more costly to provide a feature for free but have a service level agreement that requires you to maintain and update the feature. I suggest trying to avoid the complication and work out a business case that makes the feature (if not the product) more viable from a financial perspective.